# How can I automate GET calls to Microsoft Graph Explorer from a system and have the output stored via a script?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I want to download some data from Microsoft Planner and I have used the Microsoft Graph Explorer API online and have my three GET requests ready.

Let's say one of the GET requests is:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/planner/plans/E2d-w1xIyUOc6nZPfMerEmQAB266/buckets

This returns a JSON file in the 'Response Preview' pane in Microsoft Graph Explorer online.

I want to somehow initiate this GET request from a server using a script (.bat/.ps/.sh/.bash) and get this output JSON file stored on the same server.

If anyone can point me in the direction on how to achieve this, I'd be really glad?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I strongly recommend reading ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips on getting started. Your question, as it stands today, is just too broad.

Answer (score 0):

since you want a background task to run you are best registering an application without a user then once you've authenticated you can run that in a script to run say via a cron job.

If you use Laravel I've written a wrapper for graph that supports both users and tenants https://github.com/daveismyname/laravel-microsoft-graph.

Otherwise, study https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service